# How to stop capybara/selenium chrome window from coming to front/focus?

Tags: selenium, capybara

I run a test suite locally that takes about 15 minutes. During this time it's impossible to get any work done because every feature spec brings the chrome window to the front. Is there a configuration option to avoid this, to NOT bring the capybara/selenium window to the front?

This is my current config:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, 
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: {
      "chromeOptions" => {
        "args" => %w{ window-size=1740,768 } 
      }
    }
  )
end

Capybara.server_port           = 57124
Capybara.app_host              = "http://localhost:#{Capybara.server_port}" # S3 accesss control blocks default capybara 127.0.0.1
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10 #default is 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't if you want/need to run it in non-headless mode, but if you run in headless mode you won't have that issue.

Comment: ah, hm. How do I run in headless mode?

Comment: You need to add the `headless` arg (and possibly `disable-gpu` if you're on Windows) to your driver registration or if the window size is not critical to your testing you can just specify `:selenium_chrome_headless` as your javascript driver.

Comment: This is driving me nuts as well. Why can't I have it stay in the background?

Comment: @wmakley That's the way Chrome works now -- Chrome would have to change it's behavior, or you can just run it in headless mode.